# Apache Works in Single Process with httpd -X but Cannot Start Service

Tags: apache-http-server, python

I have a Python 2.7 application running on Red Hat with Apache/HTTPD.

I am setting up new servers and reached a point I cannot start the HTTPD service. The output is not descriptive at all:

```
[root@*****]# systemctl restart httpd
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@*****]# echo $?
1
[root@*****]# systemctl status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-12-23 12:42:36 CET; 2min 28s ago
     Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
  Process: 506512 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 506512 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
[root@*****]# httpd -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   *****.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost_aaa.conf:14)
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
Mutex lua-ivm-shm: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ldap-cache: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/etc/httpd/run/" mechanism=default 
Mutex cache-socache: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
PidFile: "/etc/httpd/run/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="***" id=****
Group: name="***" id=****
[root@*****]# httpd -t
Syntax OK
```

I found out that everything works OK using

```
httpd -X
```

Also there is another server where the same vhost configuration is working.

There is nothing helpful in the error_log and access_log.

Can anyone direct me to further debugging steps or propose a solution?

Comment: journal -u httpd

Comment: [root@*****]# journalctl -u httpd
    -- Logs begin at Tue 2021-12-21 20:36:17 CET, end at Tue 2021-12-21 20:36:19 CET. --
    -- No entries --

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the server had additional restrictions enforced by SELinux.

Running the command to enable HTTPD to run in multiple processes solves the problem:

```
semanage permissive -a httpd_t
```